# Overflow-y not working of content div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a overflow-y of the content only while the overflow-y of the body is hidden.

So if the content is longer that the view, there has to be an scroller.
The scroller of the div shows but isnt working:

```
<body>
        <header>  
           <div id="headerBgRight"></div>
        </header>       
        <aside class="left-panel">
           <!-- Left panel listing here -->
        </aside>
        <div class="main-content">
            <section class="form-content">

            </section>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}

header {
   background-color:#000;
   width:100%;
   height:131px;
   position:relative;
}

aside {
   height:100%;
   background-color:rgb(27,135,200);
   position: relative;
   float:left;
   width:12%;
}

.main-content {
   background-color:#999;
   width: 88%;
   position: relative;
   height: 2000px;
   float:left;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/b7xky7qp/3/)

Is it even possible what I want to achieve?

Comment: You need to use `overflow-y:scroll` on an element that has _content_ that is longer than the element. You have restricted the overflow of the element (`body`) that is the ancestor of your overly long element (`.main-content`) to be `hidden`, which of course doesn’t achieve the effect you want.

Comment: Your content inside `.main-content` has to be higher than 2000px to see the scrollbar: http://jsfiddle.net/b7xky7qp/4/ but you have already set overflow-y: hidden to body so you can't see what is at the bottom of that main-content.